# Java 8 compatibility issue: How to convert Object array to Subtype List in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

So I had a program that worked fine on Java 7 but it fails to compile with an error in Java 8. So, I went through Java Compatibility issues and I think I found out the reason (Or did I? http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7144506) . I want to know if there's a short an efficient way to replicate what my original code snippet does with Java 8. Here's a program to represent the situation. In my code there's a setter method that does the job of populating the array and I have no control on how it's populated.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        B someObject=new B();
        List<A> a = someObject.getA() == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : Arrays.asList(someObject.getA());
        for ( A item : a ) {
            System.out.println(item.value);
        }
    }
}

class A{
    String value;
    public A(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class B{
    Object[] getA(){
        Object arr[]= new Object[4];
        arr[0]=new A("hello");
        arr[1]=new A("mello");
        arr[2]=new A("jello");
        arr[3]=new A("cello");
        return arr;
    }
}
```

The error of course being:

```
HelloWorld.java:8: error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression                                                                                                
        List<A> a = someObject.getA() == null ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : Arrays.asList(someObject.getA());                                                                      
                                                                                      ^                                                                                         
    inference variable T has incompatible bounds                                                                                                                                
      equality constraints: A                                                                                                                                                   
      lower bounds: Object                                                                                                                                                      
  where T is a type-variable:                                                                                                                                                   
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)                                                                                                                         
Note: HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.                                                                                                                      
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                                                                              
1 error
```

I need a (preferrably one line/elegant) alternative method which is also efficient to accomplish the same.

**EDIT:** To clarify. I cannot control what class B returns to me. Nor can I modify class A in any way (I don't think that could help in any case). I can only control what HelloWorld does.

Comment: *I have no control on how it's populated*: does that mean that you have no idea if all it contains is instances of A? What do you want to happen if it contains Strings, or Integers, instead of As?

Comment: You answered the first question, but not the second one. If the array of objects contains something other that instances of A, what should your method do?

Comment: @jb-nizet No I know for certain that it contains instances of A just that I cannot control it. Regards.

Comment: What I intended to imply with the statement is that I cannot edit the class B. I am sorry, I should have been clearer.

Comment: Is the list changed afterwards, e.g. elements added or removed?

Comment: @Roland Yes elements may be added and removed after wards. Could you please explain how that would effect the problem?

Comment: `Arrays.asList` just returns an array-backed list, so it may not be changed in size (similar to an array). If you use `Arrays.asList(...toArray())` you need to wrap that into another mutable list, e.g. an `ArrayList`, but then again you might just use `collect(toList)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no access to B, but are sure that you get A's, you could try something like this:

```
Object[] objArray = someObject.getA(); // omit calling getA() twice
List<A> a = objArray == null ? Collections.emptyList() :
                 Stream.of(objArray)
                         .map(o -> (A) o) // or place your transform function in here
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @JBNizet pointed out: the really easiest, but unsafe and therefore not really recommended solution, is to just add a `List`-cast:

```
List<A> a = objArray == null ? Collections.emptyList() : (List)Arrays.asList(objArray);
```

If you are unsure, about what is in the array, you should rather use the following to filter out only the A's:

```
List<A> a = objArray == null ? Collections.emptyList() :
                 Stream.of(objArray)
                         .filter(o -> o instanceof A)
                         .map(o -> (A) o) // or place your transform function in here
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or the same with method references:

```
List<A> a = objArray == null ? Collections.emptyList() :
                 Stream.of(objArray)
                         .filter(A.class::isInstance)
                         .map(A.class::cast) // or place your transform function in here
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: added `objArray` to omit calling `getA()` twice as seen on @Holger's answer. Calling it twice might be more expensive than all the rest of the proposed solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you comment on if it would be similarly efficient as the old code, as I have no experience with Stream. Regards.

Comment: It may be slightly (milliseconds? nanoseconds? 0?) slower, but you keep full control on how the transformation happens, if for any reason there are not only A's in there. But if performance is an issue (e.g. you have large arrays), than you have the possibility to go parallel: `Stream.of(someObject.getA()).parallel()...`.

Comment: If you absolutely want to keep the unsafe code you have, and which could break when you get an element out of that list if it's not an A, you can just use `List<A> a = someObject.getA() == null ? Collections.emptyList() : ((List)Arrays.asList(someObject.getA()));`. I wouldn't recomment it, though.

Comment: Actually, if all you want to do is just an 'easy' way to get your `List<A>` and you don't even care about what is in there, then the `List`-cast-approach seems even better.

Comment: @JBNizet If I actually had my way with the codebase I would but I don't. I can only do what I was asked to. And what I was asked to was, change the codebase to be Java 8 compatible so that we can use Java 8 in new features with the minimum amount of change to the old code base.

Comment: @TheInquisitive1 I don't get you. You can use the stream-based, safe code in Roland's answer, or you can use the unsafe, but equivalent to what you had before, code in my comment. It's up to you to choose. But as you saw, not changing anything to the HelloWorld code won't make it compile, so you need to change the code. Choose how.

Comment: @JBNizet That's not what I mean. I'll go for Roland's approach, that was a reply "absolutely want to keep the unsafe code..." part. I can only modify HelloWorld code. I cannot modify the class B which is poorly designed. That's all I meant. Thanks.

Comment: OK. What I meant that the code which is unsafe is not in B. The code which is unsafe in your question is in HelloWorld.

Comment: That's right and both solutions don't really deal with that fact. With the stream solution you are just one step ahead to a type safe implementation, e.g. with a `.filter(o -> o instanceof A)` or similar.

Comment: @JBNizet@roland Thanks guys. It helps me to see your perspective on things. I am new to this. Regards.

Comment: No problem. As @Holger stated, your code calling `getA()`twice might not be that performant anyway. I personally would go for any stream solution (`Stream.of`, `Arrays.stream`, etc.)... the simpler, the better. Or: the more understandable, the better ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The safest solution is to copy the array into an array of the correct type, i.e.

```
Object[] array = someObject.getA();
List<A> a = array==null? Collections.emptyList():
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, A[].class));
```

with Java 8, there is the option to use the Stream API instead, which is only slightly shorter:

```
Object[] array = someObject.getA();
List<A> a = array==null? Collections.emptyList():
    Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(array).toArray(A[]::new));
```

If you worry about the array copying costs, well, in your original code you invoked `getA()` twice, imposing even higher costs than just a plain array copy. The above solutions fix that.

Performing unchecked operations “because I know what I’m doing” rarely pays off. In this specific case, you would just move the costs from the list creation to the place where the list will be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first approach is what I personally came up with at first. Then I was unsure of how the memory costs would affect the functionality. But I think you are right. This is the right way to go.

Do you think the stream approach is any slower than the first one? Also, how does it compare to the map -> collect approach suggested by Roland?

Comment: `Stream.toArray` is potentially more efficient that `Collectors.toList()` in this scenario, because it knows the number of elements in advance. So it’s on par with `Arrays.copyOf`.

Comment: I really like the `toArray(A[]::new)`-variant. Now it mainly depends on whether that `List<A>` is changed afterwards or not.

Comment: Is it possible for me to select both as accepted. I learned from both or does stack overflow not allow that?

Comment: @Roland The array list may change afterwards.

Comment: @TheInquisitive1: you can’t accept two answers, but once you have enough reputation, you can upvote all of them. Note that if you plan to modify the result list later-on, `Collections.emptyList()` is inappropriate as it is immutable. This also applies to the result of `Collectors.toList()`, which has an unspecified mutability, so it returns a mutable `ArrayList` in the current implementation, but may return an immutable list in another. So to get a mutable list, you’d have to use `toCollection(ArrayList::new)` instead. In contrast, `toArray(A[]::new)` always returns a mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] array = example.getLabelCodes();
```

> Converting Object array to List..

```
List<String> stringArray = Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(array).toArray(String[]::new));
```

> Converting List back to Object Array..

```
Object[] objectArray = stringArray.toArray();
```